# Why doesn't my code work for CardLayout? Not matter what I do, it just shows a blank JFrame

Tags: java, swing, cardlayout

No matter what I do, I can't get the JFrame to show anything. Its just blank. I added the buttons starter and tutorialer to the JPanel game and added that JPanel to the the JPanel cards which I set to a cardLayout.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
public class layouter extends JFrame {
    public static void main (String[]args){
        layouter x = new layouter();
    }
    public layouter(){
        setSize(600,600);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        Pan p = new Pan();
        setContentPane(p);
        setVisible(true);

    }
}

class Pan extends JPanel{
    JButton starter;
    JButton tutorialer;
    JPanel start;
    JPanel tutorial;
    JPanel game;
    JPanel cards;
   CardLayout cl;
        Pan(){  
        starter = new JButton("start");
        tutorialer = new JButton("tutorial");
        start = new JPanel();
        tutorial = new JPanel();
        game = new JPanel();
        cards = new JPanel( new CardLayout());
        cl= (CardLayout)(cards.getLayout());
        game.setLayout(null);
        starter.setBounds(150,150,100,50);
        tutorialer.setBounds(150,200,100,50);
         game.add(starter);
        game.add(tutorialer);
        cards.add(game,"game");
        add(cards);
    repaint();
  }

public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    cl.show(cards,"game");
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

}

Comment: This `cl.show(cards,"game");` is a bad idea within the `paintComponent` method and you should NEVER modify the state of any component from within any paint method

Comment: Thank you!, that seems to work! But why is it that Null Layout doesn't work. I used .setBounds right?

Comment: Layout managers do  more then just layout components, they provide information to parent containers about the amount of space that the container itself needs (based on it's contents)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`game.setLayout(null);` <-- This is going to cause you issues as anything your add to this container will no longer be automatically laid out.  Components by default have a size and position of 0x0

Make use of an appropriate layout manager.  See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details.

If you add any more containers to `games`, you may need to "show" the default view you want to been shown first

```
cl.show(cards, "game");
```